# Read Windows UDP Buffer Size

Tags: c++, windows, udp, buffer, command-prompt

I'm finding difficulty figuring out how to check the UDP Buffer size in Windows via Command Prompt. I am looking for something similar to the linux command "sysctl net.core.rmem_max". I do not need to set the UDP buffer size, I just need to check it in order to throw a warning if it is smaller than my recommended size. So far every where I seem to look points towards setting the buffer size through the Windows Registry. Does anyone know of a possible way to simply check the buffer size through a Command Prompt or C++?

Comment: If this question isn't about progamming it is off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do this from the command line (looks like [PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/21/querying-udp-ports-with-powershell/) can do it), but you should be able to do this in C++ as follows (note: untested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main ()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err != NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed with error " << err << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "socket failed with error " << WSAGetLastError () << "\n"
        return 1;
    }

    int rcvbuf_len;
    socklen_t optlen = sizeof (rcvbuf_len);

    if (getsockopt (s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf_len, &optlen) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "getsockopt failed with error " << WSAGetLastError () << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "UDP receive buffer length = " << rcvbuf_len << " bytes\n");
}
```

We don't need to clean up any resources here as that will happen automatically when the program exits.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne "or C++".  I will edit my answer to give you a chance to reverse your downvote.

Comment: @mar Why did you decide to down vote this answer but forget to close vote the question?

Answer (score 1):

I used the code of @Paul Sanders and added some modifications based on the official documentation of `getsockopt` function and `socket` function (can be found [here for getsockopt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt) and [here for socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket)), corrected some minor details and compiled it as

> g++ get_buff_size.cpp -o get_buff_size.exe -lwsock32

I used it to double check the information in the MS docs about the [DefaultReceiveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb726981(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#afd-registry-parameters) parameter and also trying to figure out if `DefaultReceiveWindow` applies to both TCP and UDP.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

int main()
{
    int optVal;
    int optLen = sizeof(int);

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err != NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET listenSocketTCP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (listenSocketTCP == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET listenSocketUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (listenSocketUDP == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (getsockopt(listenSocketTCP, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&optVal, &optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("TCP SO_RCVBUF Value: %d\n", optVal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("TCP SO_RCVBUF getsockopt failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (getsockopt(listenSocketTCP, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&optVal, &optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("TCP SO_SNDBUF Value: %d\n", optVal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("TCP SO_SNDBUF getsockopt failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (getsockopt(listenSocketUDP, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&optVal, &optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("UDP SO_RCVBUF Value: %d\n", optVal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("UDP SO_RCVBUF getsockopt failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (getsockopt(listenSocketUDP, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&optVal, &optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("UDP SO_SNDBUF Value: %d\n", optVal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("UDP SO_SNDBUF getsockopt failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should expect output like this:

```
TCP SO_RCVBUF Value: 65536
TCP SO_SNDBUF Value: 65536
UDP SO_RCVBUF Value: 65536
UDP SO_SNDBUF Value: 65536
```

Comment: How does it not answer the question?